# Adding multiple UIImages for Paging Enabled UIScrollView from ALAssetLibrary

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, alassetlibrary

i am having a problem with showing images after fetching from the ALAssetLibrary.My Problem is if there is one image then its coming fine but if there are multiple images then the last image is only appearing but not the prior images.I fount that there is a problem in the Loop and couldn't find if.

Please let me know if anyone resolve this.

```
mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

mainScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

mainScrollView.delegate=self;
mainScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
mainScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

CGRect innerScrollFrame = mainScrollView.bounds;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {

    imageForZooming=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

    if ([maincheck isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

        [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
         {
             UIImage  *copyOfOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
             [imageForZooming setImage:copyOfOriginalImage];
         }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"the error is %@",error);
         }];
    }

    else{
        [imageForZooming setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[images objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer*t=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showblack:)];

    t.numberOfTapsRequired=1;

    imageForZooming.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    [imageForZooming addGestureRecognizer:t];

    imageForZooming.frame=CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200);

    imageForZooming.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    imageForZooming.tag = VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG;

    pageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:innerScrollFrame];
    pageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    pageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.5f;
    pageScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0f;
    pageScrollView.contentSize = imageForZooming.bounds.size;
    pageScrollView.delegate = self;
    pageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    [pageScrollView addSubview:imageForZooming];

    [mainScrollView addSubview:pageScrollView];

    if (i < images.count-1) {
        innerScrollFrame.origin.x += innerScrollFrame.size.width;
    }
}

mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(innerScrollFrame.origin.x + innerScrollFrame.size.width,mainScrollView.bounds.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you didn't set the content size of the scroll view.

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(numberOfImages * scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.width)];
```

And also you have to change the X offset (If horizontal scrolling) for each imageView before adding to scrollView.

Also, you didn't add imageForZooming to any scrollView here.

Look [here](http://www.codeexplain.com/code/ab8dff6d-1c0e-49ca-a490-19fcfc4d16a1) to load the images from ALAssetLibrary.

Comment: I set the contentSize of the Scrollview,its working well with the width of the Scroll View but images are not appearing on it.Only problem when using ALAssetLibrary Code.the Else condition is working fine with multiple images.But not with The ASSetLibrary Condition.

Comment: Please go through the edited code and let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Are you saying "Only last image is showing if you use ALAssetLibrary and all images are getting shown in else condition?"

Comment: I found that ALAssetLybrary is working Asynchronously and it seems there is something missing out here for the proper adding of the images to the imageforZooming object.

Comment: Yes,my Problem is the what you said.

Comment: With ALAssetLibrary i can able to see only last image and all images are not appearing but the uiimage Objects are added to the ImageView with out images.But the same thing works perfectly when else condition is executing.

Comment: Once look at the link I provided in answer.